# memory_limit = 256M but still get 'Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted'

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have used php.ini to set my memory limit to 256M, and this is working checks out with phpinfo.php (Local and Master).

(note: I have also tried setting it in the .htaccess file, but this crashes my whole admin backend)

I am using WordPress 3.6 and WooCommerce Version 2.0.13

I keep getting the 'Fatal Error' message, for example if I try to add pages to a menu, or turn on any other plugins. I have found that I can deactivate WooCommerce I can add items to the menu then turn it on again, but that's kind of annoying, and soon I'm going to need to add a few more plugins.

What I don't understand is that I already have more than 33554432 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted the apache server?

in order to see the changes that we made in the php.ini always we have to restart the server. It's seems that the server stills have 32MB, because 32MB =  33554432 bytes

Greetings.

Comment: Thanks - I'll ask the host to do that, although it's weird that phpinfo says 256M

Comment: Oh, so you are hosting. You can ask them about how many memory you are allow to use.
Greetings.